# When to use default Spring Data REST behavior?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data

I recently worked on a project which uses Spring Data REST with Spring Boot. While it is GREAT to harness the power of Spring Data REST and build a powerful web service in no time, I have come to regret one thing: how tightly coupled the "presentation" layer (JSON returns) is to the underlying data structure.

Sure, I have used Projections and ResourceProcessors to manipulate the JSON, but that still does not completely sever ties with the database structure.

I want to introduce Controllers to the project, to integrate some of the "old" ways of building a web service in Spring. But how should I draw the line? I don't want to eradicate Spring Data REST from my project.

I am sure many of you have faced similar decisions, so any advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: At a colleague's suggestion, I have:  
1) Created a database view which joins together tables for a logical business need
2) Created a JPA domain object for the view, and its @RepositoryRestResource repository
3) Override all INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE endpoints from the Repository (because it is against a DB view) 
4) Moved all VIEW end points into this new repository
5) The original repository (which points at the JPA domain based on the database table) is now meant for INSERT / UPDATE /DELETE functions

Comment: The other alternative is: 1) make all the methods in the table-enabled @RepositoryRestResource have a bunch of @RestResource(exported = false) tags. This way, they would not be available via a web service call, but are still available to classes in the project; 2) create a REST Controller which calls the repository methods and then manipulate the JSON results to fit business needs before rendering them